# What is a rest-function in a Solow model?

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

I am trying to better understand the Solow-Swan growth model and the golden saving rate.
When searching around I came across a [blog](http://thinkingeconomicstogether.blogspot.com/2020/07/structure.html?m=1) explaining the intuition differently. Instead of in the standard Capital-Output figure a different figure is used with something called a Rest-function in an investment-consumption goods space. I guess this is the same as S-C if I plot it in a Solow model.
I quite like the idea but I am not sure I fully get it.
The rest function is the function of all possible steady states where the amount of saving (investment goods) equals depreciation? It has to start from 0 since there is no production (assuming a Cobb Douglas I guess) with no capital and it has to fall to no consumption goods if there is 100% saving. In between it has to be positive (reminds me of a laffer curve …)
But does it not also depend on Labour?
If the labour supply changes the rest function shifts up or better higher and a little more to the right?
What seem interesting is that if you have a change in the savings rate the closer you are to the golden rule the less the disruption - or would that be wrong?
Does anyone know where I can find more about this rest function. I don’t seem to have come across it yet elsewhere.